# How to listen port parallel in python + linux

Tags: python, linux, bash, python-3.x, parallel-processing

everyone!
I have a python script, which process input from COM-port.

```
import sys
for string in sys.stdin:
    some_calculation(string)
```

It runs like this:

```
cat -v /dev/pts/2 | python3 'process.py'
```

I want to make it parallel, for example by using GNU parallel.
My way is like this: A| parallel B

```
cat -v /dev/pts/2 | parallel  --pipe --recstart '>' python3 process.py
```

But it is not working.

Any ideas?
Many thanks.
UPDATE:
I found some solution:

```
cat /dev/pts/2 | parallel -j2 "echo {} | python3 process.py"
```

Another one by Inian:

```
cat -v /dev/pts/2 | parallel --recstart '>' --pipe python3 process.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke `GNU parallel` with the `--pipe` option as below:-

```
--pipe
        Spread input to jobs on stdin (standard input). Read a block
        of data from stdin (standard input) and give one block of data
        as input to one job.
```

Use the `restart` flag before the `--pipe`

```
cat -v /dev/pts/2 | parallel --recstart '>' --pipe python3 process.py
```

More info about [`GNU parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html).

Comment: It works! But some error:
parallel: Warning: A full record was not matched in a block. Increasing to --blocksize 1363150.
--blocksize 1772096
...
--blocksize 14455562

what is it?
Thanks.

Comment: @user7198142: you have to set the `--blocksize` explicitly in the command. The warning is thrown because it does not know how much number of blocks to read for a given parallel instance. Generally If you set '--blocksize' to at least 2 times the max record size, you will never see the warning. The default block size is 1MB

Comment: Thanks, I will check it as answer!
I have last question, please ask: what I should set (blocksize of somrthing else), if I want process the data as soon as possible, and the output is just line of 180 bytes? The data continuously provided.

Comment: `parallel` automatically throws a warning like you saw before, if your input is less than the amount that could be actually parallelised.

Comment: Ok, but it thrown warning to any block size..
I have a continuously data flow from COM-port.

Comment: @user7198142: Have you set any value for `--blocksize`, in your command currently? What is that value?

Comment: Yes, `cat -v /dev/pts/2 | parallel --block 100M --recstart '>' --pipe python3 process.py`

changed --block 1M -- 1000M, nothing %(

Comment: Ok, This works:

`cat -v /dev/pts/2 | parallel -j2 --pipe --block 12M python3 ppp.py`

But key -j 2 doesn't work, (in top process no 2 python process)

Comment: I just must use double --.
Thank you!